# MySQL+PHP Error: mysqli_stmt::execute() Incorrect datetime value: "

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm new in PHP and MySQLi and trying to create an `editable paginated table`. But I'm getting stuck on date time update.

My add function works fine but when I'm trying to submit edit form I'm getting the following error:

> mysqli_stmt::execute(): (22007/1292): Incorrect datetime value: "for column 'date'

Here is the part of errored lines code:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = htmlentities($_POST['name'], ENT_QUOTES);
$nummer = htmlentities($_POST['nummer'], ENT_QUOTES);
$stuck = htmlentities($_POST['stuck'], ENT_QUOTES);
$cdate = date(' Y-m-d H:i:s');

//check if empty
if($name == '' || $nummer == '' || $cdate = '' || $stuck == ''){
    $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
    renderForm($name, $nummer, $cdate, $stuck, $error, $id);
}else{
    // if everything is fine, update the record in the database
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE ware SET name = ?, nummer = ?, date= ?, stuck = ? WHERE id=?")){
        $stmt->bind_param("sssii",$name,$nummer, $cdate,  $stuck, $id);
        if(!$stmt->execute()) echo $stmt->error;
        ...
```

The full code can be found here: http://pastie.org/10824477

Comment: I see there is a extra white space in date function. Try using this $cdate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

Comment: You could just use `now()` in your query assuming your DB and PHP are running the same timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake.

```
 if($name == '' || $nummer == '' || $cdate = '' || $stuck == ''){
```

should be

```
 if($name == '' || $nummer == '' || $cdate == '' || $stuck == ''){
```

Solved!

Answer (score 1):

@Ravinder Reddy beat me to it, but I noticed you have an extra white space in the `date` function:

```
$cdate = date(' Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

should be

```
$cdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

the mysql `now()` function would work here also.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function logout($terget=NULL){
    @session_start();
    $cDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $ipvar=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $member_idV = $this->get_session("member_id");              
    $columns = array("datevar", "member", "ipvar", "logType");
    $values = array("$cDate", "$member_idV", "$ipvar", "Log Out");
    $table = "report_log";
    $rsADD = $this->insert($columns,$values,$table);
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    if( $terget == "" ){
        $path = '/index.php';
    } else
    {
        $path = $terget;
    }   
    $this->redirect("$path");       `
}
```